# Create multiple child processes and run execvp

Tags: c, linux, fork, execvp

I have a function in `C` which creates a child process and makes it run `execvp`.

```
int Execute(char **arg)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    if ((pid=fork()) == 0)
    {

        execvp(arg[0],arg);

        perror("Execvp error");
        exit(1);
    }

    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        perror("Fork error");
        exit(2);
    }
}
```

Now I want to alter the function to actually run `execvp` several times (for example 5), and make the parent process wait for all the children to finish. Tried wrapping it all in `for` loop, but `execvp` gets executed just once. I know that basically `execvp` 'replaces' the current program code, but have no idea whether the iteration does not go on.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Note that `exit` is not signal-safe, you should not use it after `fork` in the child process. Prefer `_Exit`.

Comment: Can you show us your loop? Be careful to exit the loop when in a child, and call fork only in the parent process. Also mind that you probably have to collect all child PIDs.

Comment: Why do you show the code that is working and hide the version this question is about, will say the code that isn't working?

Comment: OT: `status` is undefined.

Comment: @alk Sorry, was playing on my own with this `for` loop and had to clean up to show the code. Forgotten to include `status` declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, loop around the process creation collecting the child PIDs

```
pid_t pid[5];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if ((pid[i]=fork()) == 0) {
      execvp(arg[0],arg);

      perror("Execvp error");
      _exit(1);
  }
  if (pid[i] < 0) {
    perror("Fork error");
  }
}
```

Second, loop around the waitpid call for every valid PID.

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
  if (pid[i] > 0) {
    int status;

    waitpid(pid[i], &status, 0);
    if (status > 0) {
      // handle a process sent exit status error
    }
  } else {
    // handle a proccess was not started
  }     
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. It does work, but is it necessary to make two loops (maybe there's other way)? Seems a bit 'not right', but maybe just for me.

Comment: Do I understand your question right, that you want to start the child processes quickly and run them in parallel? The call to waitpid or wait does block your parent process until the child finished, that's why you do that as late as possible.

Comment: Yes, correct. I need to run them and either wait for all of them, or not (two scenarios, but I know how to handle them). When it comes to waiting, I know there's `wait(NULL);`, which waits for all the child processes to finish and I thought the second `for` loop can be replaced by it, but it does not work. Maybe there's a way to get it working in this scenario?

Comment: wait(0) will only wait until a single child process finishes, so you will need a loop around the wait calls anyway.

Comment: @bdruemen: One could pass `WNOHANG` as 3rd argument to `waitpid()` to keep it from blocking. This way "doing all in one loop" would be possible.

Comment: Yes, but in the end you would need to loop around waitpid() until you have collected the exit status of each child process.

Comment: @bdruemen Could you please update your answer to show a scenario where parent process just creates children processes but does not wait for them to finish? Tried just using the first `for` loop but my program just 'hangs'. In other words, I need my parent process to also launch `execvp` several times using child processes in the background.

Comment: @Danddry That's easy: Just not call wait, or waitpid at all.
I you are calling waitpid with WNOHANG too early, it would just return 0 and have no positive effect.